# How to search by tag using AWS PS Cmdlet: Get-EC2Subnet

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use the PS AWS Cmdlet **Get-EC2Subnet** to get the resourceId:

```
Get-EC2Subnet -filter tag:Name,Value=Test-APP-Subnet-A
```

I am trying to filter based on the resource name.
The documentation is not very helpful:

```
-Filter <Filter[]>
   One or more filters.
   ...
   tag:<key> - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the filter value. For example, to find all resources that have a tag with the key Owner and the value TeamA, specify tag:Owner for the filter name and TeamA for the filter value.
   ...
```

What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

Playing with this as well. I found that the get-ec2Instance had a better example of using filters and adapted it to this.

#Returns all subnets with a tag called "Name" defined:

```
Get-EC2Subnet -Filter @{name="tag-key";values="Name"}
```

#Returns all subnets with a specific tag "Name" set:

```
Get-EC2Subnet -Filter @{name="tag:Name";values="Test-APP-Subnet-A"}
```